# Momentary\Pushbutton Latch Switch

Tags: led, switches, toggle-switch

I'm trying to make a circuit that will latch on\off with a pushbutton. This is what I have, but the LED just stays on even though the current shows the latch is working. Thoughts? Thanks :)

[image: Latching Switch]

Comment: Why do you have a 100Ω resistor in **parallel** with your LED?

Comment: Just the way the schematic I pulled some of this from had it set up.

Comment: @DominicLuciano what software are you using for those schematics?

Answer (score 1):

A thought:

S1, below, is a SPDT (Form C) momentary pushbutton switch, and you can get rid of all that circuitry with a single chip, like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

On second thought:

[image]

Comment: That neat! Except everything has to be SMD and tiny at that, and I need more of an SPST solution

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd think my offering wasn't surface mount and **much** smaller than yours, but my edit should easily take care of any of those doubts.

Comment: No no, I knew yours was smaller, but I'm still learning about how small SMD gets, so sometimes small is still large until I read the datasheet and it's like, "Better get a microscope".

Your revision starts with the LED on, and push the button just momentarily turns it off

Comment: Not true. My revision starts with the LED either ON or OFF, and pushing the button causes it to change state and stay in that state until the button is pressed again, changing its state, and so on...  If you want the LED to start in a  known state, then use an RC integrator connected to either SET- or RESET- to get that done.

Answer (score 0):

You have drain and source swapped on Q4, your output P-channel MOSFET. The body diode is passing current regardless of the state of the gate.

Comment: No such luck when I unswapped it. The LED still stays on

Answer (score 0):

[image: 4093 Latch]

This guy seems to work. Thanks guys :)